# What is efficient way to transfer a large file from server to multiple clients?

Tags: sockets, networking, file-io, network-programming, network-protocols

I have a requirement to transfer/multicast a large file about >40g of file from a server to multiple clients at the same time and this will be done for only once. Is there any good protocol to do that in Linux? I tried using UFTP, but it didn't work.

Comment: Is this a one off or a regular thing? If a regular thing why so much data - is a partial update possible?4

Comment: Does the data have to be transferred reliably? If no, then consider using UDP Multicasting. Each client subscribes to a Multicast IP, then you can send the data one time to that IP and the network will broadcast the data to all subscribers for you. But if you need reliability then use TCP, but it has no broadcasting capabilities so you have to copy the full data to each client individually.

Comment: BitTorrent comes to mind, but recommendation questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I've had success using multicast over a LAN (as Remy recommends above), and dealing with lost packets by having any clients that missed a packet send a request back to the server asking it to retransmit the packet.  (For this to work well you should include with each packet a header file indicating the offset-from-top-of-file of its contents, so that clients can easily track which parts of the file they have and which parts they don't have / still need to get)

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "I tried using UFTP, but it didn't work"?  What didn't work?  What was the error?  UFTP should work just fine for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

[UFTP](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net) should be a good tool for this situation.  If the server and clients are on the same LAN, there shouldn't be any issue with them communicating.  If there are one or more routers separating them, then you would either have to configure routers to allow multicast traffic to pass or you could use UFTP's proxy servers to create a bridge between different network segments.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the excellent bittorrent protocol and make it private by using **Bittorent Sync**.
Go to [Bittorrent Sync Web Site](http://www.bittorrent.com/sync) for details.
The main advantages I see are :

- It's design to transport large files (if you have a network disruption it's not a problem)
- It's free
- It's cross plateform : Windows, Linux (i386, x64, ARM, PowerPC), FreeBSD, Mac, Android, IOS, and more ...
- It's secure (you provide the encryption keys)
- It's quite simple to configure

Comment: Also btsync (now resillio sync) will not transmit data outside of the LAN for local connections.